# Linux: Compare repertories with a loop

Tags: linux, loops

I would like to compare two directories, and be able to copy one file from a directory to an other ( for example, copy the file dog.png from the directory 1 to the directory 2 if this one doesn't have this file)

I know that there is the "diff" command `diff -rq rep1 rep2` which include recursion, but I don't think that the result is convenient (the way it's presented) to work with it. Plus , it doesn't care about the path as long as there is the same file somewhere in the second directory.

My idea was to list the elements of the rep1 , then do a loop, and if there is an other directory, open it and do another loop, do that until there are only files and then compare and go back to the previous loop. I know that seems like recursion, I wanted to know if it was possible to make it that way ? Or if it's too complex.

Comment: What does "repertories" mean? I have never heard that term used in computing and the dictionary doesn't list any computing meaning either. And what does "copy one file from the repertory who got it" mean? Your question is very unclear. Perhaps some examples may help.

Comment: I meant directories , sorry ! I want to copy each file from a directory to an other directory. For example, if I have a file called "dog.png" in rep1/images/dog.png and i don't have the same in the other directory (rep2/images/dog.png) then I'll copy the file from the rep1 to the rep2

Comment: Then why not `cp -r rep1/* rep2`? The `-r` means copy recursively.

Comment: It sounds sort of like you're trying to recreate `rsync`, so perhaps you can just use it instead.

Comment: I've corrected my first post. My goal is to compare two directories (let's say rep1 and rep2) and then copy the directories and files from the rep1 to the rep2 (if it's missing) . My concern is about how to compare, more precisely about how to check each directory included, is there a way to use recursion or a loop to do that ? Or would it be too complex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike C: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would try posing this Q to another site https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ as it does not quite fit the "norm" for Stack Overflow where usually you ask questions about concrete code.I'm going to try to answer the Q anyways.

Yes you could solve this with recursion. You would make one function or method that takes the full path to a directory as it's input, then that function would list all sub-directories and call itself on each of them.

The fact taht you will be scanning two directories in paralelle will add some complexity, because you have to decide what to do in 3 cases:

- Subdir exists only in A
- Subdir exists only in B
- Subdir exists in both

I would implement this by passing TWO full paths to the function, and simply change behsaviour when one of them was `null`.